# HTML5 Audio Play Button Does Not Work in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, html5-audio

I am currently unable to get the HTML5 audio player play button to work in order to play back an audio file within Internet Explorer.

On page load, I have a number of rows present, each with audio players to play back a file. All of these players work and play back the relevant file.

On selecting an option on the page, javascript is used to change the page content. The layout is similar, but just one row is present (which happens to be the same as one of the rows previously). When trying to play back the audio now, the play button doesn't respond (not even changing to pause). Right clicking the player and selecting play works fine.

I've checked the DOM and the audio element seems to be OK:

```
<audio controls="controls" preload="none" id="audio-11591-2364252-1413560341" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
<source src="audiostore.php?uid=11591&amp;file=2364252&amp;type=mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

It all works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Any thoughts on why the play button may not be working or a way to work around this?

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: Currently testing in IE11

Comment: So is the audio element not showing up at all in IE or is it just not playing?

Comment: Audio element shows up fine, it just won't play using the play button. Right clicking on the element and selecting play from the menu works fine

Answer (score 0):

If the audio just doesn't play there is a fine chance that you are ignoring a pop-up at the bottom ".. is blocking ActiveX" with an "unblock" button. Click the "unblock" button and the ActiveX will be working now and the audio will play. It worked for me perfectly. For some reason I had to click it every time I open a new tab though

Comment: The audio element isn't an ActiveX component (it's native in HTML5).

Comment: I know but i guess IE threats it like ActiveX component. Just saying what got my test to work.

Comment: You probably have a plugin installed like Quicktime or similar which intercepts the filetype(s) for audio.